# Strategy Pattern com Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-pattern, microsserviços

Tenho buscado soluções de strategy pattern com spring boot, mas nada que encontrei até então parece performático ou mesmo funcional.

Eu tenho uma interface como:

```
public interface UserService {
    User getById(Integer id);
}
```

E possuo duas inplementações distintas:

```
@Primary
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Override
    public User getById(Integer id){
    //todo here
    }
}

@Service("userRemoteService")
public class UserRemoteServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Override
    public User getById(Integer id){
    //todo here
    }
}
```

No controlador eu chamo a interface:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //some methods here

}
```

Da forma como está apenas o `UserServiceImpl` será instanciado e chamado, pois é o primary.

A aplicação pode ter dois estados, um na qual ela faz consultas no banco local e outra onde ele faz requests a um microserviço. Eu preciso que quando o estado mudar (alguma request em um endpoint vai me avisar isso e já está implementado) eu altere a implementação do UserService que será consumida pelo controlador.

Encontrei algumas soluções, a maioria são versões de if else. Eu preciso encontrar alguma solução que quando eu fizer um refresh scope do estado e ele mude, sem verificar a cada request eu tenha a implementação certa do UserService no controlador.

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: https://lofidewanto.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/creating-spring-bean-dynamically-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma alternativa. Espero que ajude!

Interface:

```
public interface UserService {
  User getById(Integer id);
}
```

Implementações:

```
@Bean(name = "userLocalService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

  @Override
  public User getById(Integer id){
    //todo here
  }
}

@Bean(name = "userRemoteService")
public class UserRemoteServiceImpl implements UserService{

  @Override
  public User getById(Integer id){
    //todo here
  }
}
```

Interface factory:

```
public interface UserServiceFactory {
  UserService getUserService(String userServiceType);
}
```

Classe de configuração:

```
@Configuration()
public class UserServiceConfig {

  @Bean
  public UserService userServiceImpl() {
    return new UserServiceImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserService UserRemoteServiceImpl() {
    return new UserRemoteServiceImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean() {
    ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
    serviceLocatorFactoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(UserServiceFactory.class);
    return serviceLocatorFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConditionUserService() {
      return new ConditionUserService();
  }
}
```

Serviço que irá definir qual implementação utilizar:

```
@Service
public class ConditionUserService() {

  private String userServiceType = "userLocalService";

  @Autowired
  private UserServiceFactory userServiceFactory;

  public UserService getUserService() {
    return userServiceFactory.getUserService(userServiceType);
  }

  public setUserServiceType(String userServiceType) {
    this.userServiceType = userServiceType;
  }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private ConditionUserService conditionUserService;

  public User getById(Integer id) {
        UserService userService = conditionUserService.getUserService();
        return userService.getById(id);
    }

}
```

No momento que você quiser mudar o comportamento você irá chamar:

```
conditionUserService.setUserServiceType("userRemoteService");
```